# Booting from live USB of Ubuntu 12.10 stops at black screen

Tags: 12.10, boot

Using liveUSB I created a bootable USB with Ubuntu 12.10 desktop.  When I boot from the USB it always stops at a black screen.  How can I tell what's going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me on my HP laptop. For some reason, it just refuses to boot with a usb drive.
I tried all sorts of different software to create the liveUSB.

In the end, I had to use a DVD, and it worked fine. Try that. Hopefully it will work.

You can burn a DVD by downloading the operating system iso and burning it to a disk using Brasero or equivalent software.

Comment: I'll give that a shot as well, but I'd really like to be able to use the USB.  I'm suspecting some sort of driver issue with the video card.  It actually seems that it is booted up, I just can't see anything on the screen.

Comment: It is indeed an issue with the video driver/card. I have an ATI card that is hybrid with an Intel one. It's hell.

Comment: Yogesh, is there a way to update the USB outside of Linux so that it does have the drivers it needs?  Thanks!

Comment: Not that I know of.